# Can we apply custom WebContentTypeMapper only to a particular WCF call?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service that accepts only requests of **Content-Type=application/json**. I want my service to accept text/plain request only for a particular `OperationContract`. I can use a custom `WebContentTypeMapper` to make the service to treat text/plain requests as application/json but I don't know how to scope it to only a particular `OperationContract`.
Sample stub -

```c#
public class MyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   public string Foo(string arg1, string arg2)
   {
      //Do something
   }

   [OperationContract]
   public string Bar(string arg1, string arg2)
   {
      //Do something else
   }
}

public class JsonContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
   public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
   {
      if( contentType.ToLowerInvariant() == "text/plain;charset=utf-8" )
      {
         // The check below fails because for each request this function is called twice.
         // The HttpContext is set the first time and its empty the second time.
         if( HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("Foo") )
         {
            return WebContentFormat.Json;
         }
         return WebContentFormat.Default;
      }
   }
}
```

**Context**: During app closing I'm sending a sendBeacon request to my service to do cleanup. sendBeacon requests cannot have content-type=application/json. I can't use sync-xhr because it is being deprecated in Chrome and are a blocking call and hang navigation to next page. I can't use async-xhr because this request will be called in `unload` event during which the browsers ignore async-xhr requests.